# Appharbor build error: Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices"

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices, appharbor

I am new to AppHarbor and am getting this build error with my project (Asp.net / C# web service). My hello world worked fine and is deployed. However, this new method that I wrote connects to Exchange using EWS Managed package.

It works fine on my local, but not on AppHarbor. I have tried setting the Precompilation to False, but the error remains. Here is the detail text....Any pointers / help will be greatly appreciated.

1>Project "D:\temp\aeprsuko.xdi\input\exchangeservice\exchangeservice.sln" (1) is building "D:\temp\aeprsuko.xdi\input\exchangeservice\exchangeservice\exchangeservice.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
     2>PrepareForBuild:
         Creating directory "obj\Release\".
       ResolveAssemblyReferences:
         Primary reference "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices".
     2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\temp\aeprsuko.xdi\input\exchangeservice\exchangeservice\exchangeservice.csproj]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you're not pushing the relevant dll with your app, and if you are you are probably referencing it in the location it has on your local machine and lot the location that's local to your app.

Try using the [NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/EWS2.0/) instead or make sure that you're pushing the dll with your code. There's more help on these sorts of problems in the [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: Thanks friism. I added the NuGet package for Exchange Web Services, and it worked like a charm. And to think that I had spend countless hours figuring this out. Frankly, I did not know that they had NuGet package for it.<br/>Here are the steps for other newbies like me:  Right click on the project icon in the Visual Studio's Solution Explorer view

Comment: Here are the steps for other newbies like me:  Right click on the project icon in the Visual Studio's Solution Explorer view and select 'Manage NuGet Packages'. Then search for the appropriate package and add it to your project. Then make sure that the package folder and the package.xml file is part of your commit to AppHarbor and the project will build successfully. Thanks SO for rescuing me again.

Answer (score 0):

In the references for your project you can try setting "Copy Local" to true?

Comment: Thanks for your response Bill. I had tried doing it both ways (with Copy local set to false and true). The NUGET suggestion from friism worked for me.